# how to make new custom emotion keyboard for ios (somewhat like Emoji)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, keyboard, emoji

What I want to make is emotion keyboard so that I can use the same in iPhone. When I searched, I found [Emoji](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4976) is better one to take ideas.

Inshort, I want to make app which would be keyboard and that can be used anywhere in messenger.

Any idea/ inputs how to go ahead to create app like Emoji?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : I am first trying to get ideas how that can be done. Hence I asked... I know this is not a small task..

Comment: "Trying to get ideas" isn't really what this site is for,

Comment: If you are trying to make an app, that will install another Emoji keyboard to system (to be able to use the keyboard in **other apps**) I have bad new for you. This is not possible, unless you are targeting Jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: atleast some insight what to do?

Comment: @iMartin : Yes, I want to make another keyboard like Emoji (but not emoji) where I will have my own images of emotions. So I can't make another keyboard like that?

Comment: @FahimParkar Why don't you try creating a new one as you said, and posts your isssues that you are having while creating new keyboard?

Comment: @FahimParkar I saw this source while googling.. Its for android.. If you try then you can port it to iOS I think. https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard Try this.

Comment: The `Emoji` chars are part of the unicode system, and the point is you can use the unicode chars on every platform, because it is a standard. every image has a unique code in the unicode table, (like the letter `A` has) for that code the current platform shows the current character of the selected font-set. making random images (of codes) won't work, because they are **not** part of the standards, and the receiver **has to have** the key to decode the special image (or codes) like the Skype or Messenger do inside the house but they won't be part of the standard unicode table.

Comment: @holex : That means I can't use Images. What actually my client wanted is make a keyboard where there will be more emotions, there will be all flags of the world, there would be Hi, Hello, How are you words... but its seems as I can't use images (and unicode will not be there for all what I want), I won't be able to make keyboard...

Comment: @FahimParkar, yes, shortly, it is the situation. you can use standard unicode chars worldwide, or you can use your special images in your application only. you might find **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)** a bit more about the `Emoji` charset, unicode codes, and it shows you how the most of the `Emoji` chars will appear on different platforms. it is just a quick review of it.

Comment: @holex : Thanks for all details. can you have all this in answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @FahimParkar, I've created an answer for it, if you'd like, you could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Emoji` chars are part of the unicode system, and the point is you can use the unicode chars on every platform, because it is a standard.

every "image" has a unique code in the unicode table, (like the letter `A` has) for that code the current platform shows the current character of the selected font-set.

making random images (of codes) won't work, because they are **not** part of the standards, and the receiver **has to have** the key to decode the special image (or codes) like the Skype or Messenger do inside the house but they won't be part of the standard unicode table.

you can use standard unicode chars worldwide, or you can use your special images in your application only. you might find **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)** a bit more about the `Emoji` charset, unicode codes, and it shows you how the most of the `Emoji` chars will appear on different platforms.

it is just a quick review of it.