# Custom keyboard with emoji (like kimoji)?

Tags: ios, ios8, emoji, custom-keyboard

I was wondering how the [KIMOJI](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kimoji/id1068019093?mt=8) works?
I read everywhere that you can only create custom keyboards which insert text, not custom emoji.

Any ideas?

Comment: see this link it may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919532/how-to-make-new-custom-emotion-keyboard-for-ios-somewhat-like-emoji

Comment: In KIMOJI app you have to copy and paste it to text field. We can't enter directly enter sticker in text area.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had been wondering how to create a custom keyboard extension inspired by KIMOJI for stickers and just finished writing a response here: [Add Stickers in Custom KeyBoard Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741015/add-stickers-in-custom-keyboard-extension/37019342#37019342)

The only modification I would suggest is that instead of using UIViews to hold a few buttons, you may want to try holding many stickers in a UICollectionView. The KIMOJI app allows you to scroll horizontally through the stickers/emoji and a UICollectionView would allow you that functionality.

I hope this helps.